# Python 3.4 async mechanisms

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.4

What async mechanisms will python 3.4 support? Will it be like node`s event loop or something else? And will it require different libraries (async ones) to be written to support it?

Comment: Have you read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.4 is attempting to bring to the
standard library a standard reference implemenation
of an event loop.

I believe Guido has been developed this
and it's called Tulip.

See:

- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/

Video PyCon Talk:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1coLC-MUCJc

Comment: Tulip is connected to the new async features in 3.4? I see requirements for tulip to be "Python from 2.6 to 3.x" and version 0.1.0, seems strange.

Comment: I recommend you read the PEP on it :)

Comment: Whoops sorry posted a wrong link!